# jQuery Mobile Popup No Button if Element Info is in URL Bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm using the popup object from jQuery Mobile, and it gets called to show a certain amount of time after the page loads, which adds the element ID prepended by the pound sign (`#`) at the top of the URL. (e.g. http://url.com/page.html#element)

Now this reference goes away when the popup is closed, but if the page is refreshed while it's open, the reference stays there, and for some reason this causes the close button at the top right to not get rendered, which displays "close" in it's place (should be the circular gray button with an 'X' in the center).

HTML:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="test_popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-content"> <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a> 
    <p>
        <img src="namechange.png" />
    </p>
</div>Hello World
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var popup = $('#test_popup');
    popup.popup();
    setTimeout(function () {
        popup.popup('open');
    }, 2000);

    $(document).on('popupafteropen', '.ui-popup', function () {
        var popup = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            popup.popup('close');
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jpzkngf6/ (Although I know that this makes it hard to test for the element reference at the top, since JSFiddle doesn't seem to show them at the top, but it's the best I could do since I don't have a host to the file on)

Why is this happening? And how do I stop this from happening?